# How height is calculated without setting it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get more efficient with building responsive websites and since I'm using Bootstrap (not particularly important for this case - I believe), I was looking into [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/). I decided to view the site's source and noticed one thing I've never seen before: they did not set a height for any of their containers except for the whole page wrapper and the footer. This baffles me because everything falls into place with the website and it's super repsonsive. I understand the elements where they use Bootstrap's classes like "col-sm-4" and whatnot but does anyone understand the art of making the header, a content container, etc calculate heights without specifying in css? Can anyone explain this concept? I tried Googling but not sure of the correct keywords to find answers.

Also, if you need to see yourself, [here](http://bootsnipp.com/css/bootsnipp.css?ver=20dfa789c2d17f69d7b957a95712b9f0) is the link to their CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understanding the Box Model is important. As an (overly simplified) rule of thumb, you can think of it like this; there are 2 primary types of elements: *inline* (`span`, `b`, `strong`, ...) and **block** (`div`, `p`, ...).

**Block** tags by default are `width: 100%`. That is to say they will naturally stretch to fill their horizontal area.

*Inline* tags you can think of as being constricting. They shrik to fit the size of their inner elements. This makes sense when you think of a bold tag: it is not unlike highlighting the text you want to be bold. It stays small to fit the content.

In both cases, though, unless you specify a `height`, both **block** and *inline* tags will shrink their `height` to fit their inner elements. Because of this, you can think of a website as being a bunch of elements stacked on top of each other, where the top of the page is the bottom of the "stack".

Here is an example of divs without specified heights having their heights changed by the size of the interior content. http://jsfiddle.net/S3q2C/ Notice all the divs have a border to easily see its relative size.

Comment: block elements by default **fill** 100% but are set to `width: auto` ;)

Comment: Good catch! I will keep the answer as is for oversimplification purposes, but you are absolutely right.

Comment: @BenRoux The theory makes sense but I may have to see it. Looking at the Bootsnipp website, I still don't understand how the divs seem perfect in height. I forgot to mention there is a navbar with a ```min-height``` of 50px, but there are four more divs between that and the footer that do not specify a height. For example, why didn't the header banner have a bigger height and the sections below get smaller?

Comment: @MartavisP. Added an example to my answer to better illustrate the shrink-to-fit height, while adjusting the size of the interior elements

Comment: Amazing! I completely understand what's going on now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set an explicit height, containers will automatically grow to fit the content (respectively). Sometimes this is desirable, other times not (think overflow hidden). A possible reason why people use explicit heights in containers could be because of absolute positioning, or if they want to align a nested element that is 50px tall, with another that is 200px tall. An explicit height could also be used to maintain perspective say for a picture or other element (maybe a series of elements). While this answer is the end all be all you might be looking for, the key thing I'm trying to pass along is that an explicit height is used when needed, not all the time.

Here's a quick demo showing you two `<div>` containers, one with a height set, and another with no height.

http://jsfiddle.net/xrZ73/1/

Comment: Ok, I believe in my comment above I may have said something that ties to this answer? So are you saying that as long as the top element has a height (in the case of Bootsnipp with a navbar set at ```min-height: 50px```), that the rest of the elements will be perfect?